# Adding additional search for reference in Joomla component

Tags: php, search, model, joomla3.0

I am using a real estate component that has a front-end admin area to view property listings. An additional field was added to a section called custom fields that is named Ref (Reference). In the admin listings I am trying to add an additional search that searches for that reference. There are three tables involved here:

`1j0_cddir_jomestate`  Which holds the property listings information such as title and description.
`1j0_cddir_fields`   which is the custom fields created.
`1j0_cddir_content_has_fields`   and this holds the values of the custom fields

I would need to join `1j0_cddir_content_has_fields` "fields_id" with `1j0_cddir_fields` "id" and `1j0_cddir_jomestate` "id" must join `1j0_cddir_content_has_fields` "content_id"

I am struggling to figure out how to add this function to the models/admin_listings.php so that I may add that search input to the admin_listings view.

```
<?php

    protected $text_prefix = 'COM_JOMESTATE';
    protected $user;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->user=JFactory::getUser();
        $this->planID=$this->getPlanID();
    }
    protected function getListQuery()
    {

        // Initialise variables.
        $db     = $this->getDbo();
        $query  = $db->getQuery(true);

        if ($this->planID->profile=='company'){
            $query->select(
                $this->getState(
                    'list.select',
                    'a.id AS id, a.title AS title, a.date_created, a.featured, a.users_id, a.published, '.
                    'c.title as category_title,a.date_publish,a.date_publish_down,ag.first_name,ag.last_name'
                )
            );
        }else{
            $query->select(
                $this->getState(
                    'list.select',
                    'a.id AS id, a.title AS title, a.featured, a.date_created, a.users_id, a.published, '.
                    'c.title as category_title,a.date_publish,a.date_publish_down'
                )
            );
        }

        $query->from($db->quoteName('#__cddir_jomestate').' AS a');

         $query->select('COUNT(l.id) AS viewHow, SUM(l.view_item) AS viewSum');
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__cddir_statistic AS l ON (l.item_id = a.id AND l.extension=\'com_jomestate\')');  

        // Join over the categories.
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__cddir_categories AS c ON c.id = a.categories_id');
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__cddir_categories AS e ON e.id = a.categories_address_id');

        if ($this->planID->profile=='company'){
            $query->join('LEFT', '#__cddir_agent AS ag ON a.users_id = ag.users_id');
            $query->join('LEFT', '#__cddir_company AS co ON co.id = ag.company_id');
        }

        $query->join('LEFT', '#__users AS u ON u.id = a.users_id');

        // Filter by published published
        $published = $this->getState('filter.published');
        if (is_numeric($published)) {
            $query->where('a.published = '.(int) $published);
        }

        // Filter by category.
        $categoryId = $this->getState('filter.categories_id');
        if (is_numeric($categoryId) && $categoryId!=0) {
            $cat_tbl = JTable::getInstance('Category', 'JomcomdevTable');
            $cat_tbl->load($categoryId);
            $rgt = $cat_tbl->rgt;
            $lft = $cat_tbl->lft;
            $baselevel = (int) $cat_tbl->level;
            $query->where('c.lft >= '.(int) $lft);
            $query->where('c.rgt <= '.(int) $rgt);
        }

        $search = $this->getState('filter.search');
        if (!empty($search)) {
            if (stripos($search, 'id:') === 0) {
                $query->where('a.id = '.(int) substr($search, 3));
            } else {
                $search = $db->Quote('%'.$db->escape($search, true).'%');
                $query->where('(a.title LIKE '.$search.' OR a.alias LIKE '.$search.')');
            }
        }

        if ($this->planID->profile=='company'){
            $query->where('(a.users_id ='.(int) $this->user->id.' or co.users_id='.(int) $this->user->id.')');
        }
        else $query->where('a.users_id ='.(int) $this->user->id);


        $sort = $this->getState('list.sort');
        switch($sort) {
            case 'most_viewed':
                $query->order($db->escape('viewSum DESC, a.date_publish DESC'));
                break;
            case 'alfa':
                $query->order($db->escape('a.title, a.date_publish DESC'));
                break;
            case 'featured':
                $query->order($db->escape('a.featured DESC, a.date_publish DESC'));
                break;
            case 'latest':
            default:
                $query->order($db->escape('a.date_publish DESC'));
        }

        $query->group($db->escape('a.id'));
        return $query;
    }
    function getCategories()
    {
        $cat_array = array(array('v'=>'','t'=>JText::_('COM_JOMESTATE_ADM_ALL')));
        $query = "SELECT title, id, level FROM #__cddir_categories WHERE extension='com_jomestate.jomestate' ORDER BY lft";
        $data = $this->_getList($query);
        foreach ($data as $row):
            for ($i=1;$i<$row->level;$i++) $row->title="&#160;&#160;&#160;".$row->title;
            $temp_array=array('v'=>$row->id,'t'=>$row->title);
            array_push($cat_array,$temp_array);
        endforeach;
        return $cat_array;
    }

    /**
     * Method to auto-populate the model state.
     *
     * Note. Calling getState in this method will result in recursion.
     *
     * @since   1.6
     */
    protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null)
    {
            // Initialise variables.
            $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

            // Load the parameters.
//            $params = $app->getParams();
            $params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_jomestate');

            $menu = $app->getMenu();
            $this->active = $menu->getActive();
            if ($this->active) {
                    $menuParams = $this->active->params;
                    $global = $menuParams->get('global_option');
                    if(!$global) {
                        $paramsa = $menuParams->toArray();
                        $paramsb = $params->toArray();
                        foreach($paramsa AS $key=>$p) $paramsb[$key] = $p;
                        $newObject = (object) $paramsb;
                        $newObject->activeItemid = $this->active->id;
                        $params->loadObject($newObject);
                    }
            }            
            $this->setState('params', $params);

            $limit = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.list.limit', 'jdItemsPerPage', $params->get('listing_per_page'), 'uint');
            $this->setState('list.limit', $limit);

            $value = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.list.limitstart', 'limitstart', 0);
            $limitstart = ($limit != 0 ? (floor($value / $limit) * $limit) : 0);

            $this->setState('list.start', $limitstart);

            $search = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.search', 'filter_search', '', 'string');
            $this->setState('filter.search', $search);

            $categoryId = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.categories_id', 'filter_category', '', 'string');
            $this->setState('filter.categories_id', $categoryId);


            $sort = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.list.sort', 'jdItemsSort', 'latest', 'string');
            $this->setState('list.sort', $sort);

    }

    public function getUserStateFromRequest($key, $request, $default = null, $type = 'none', $resetPage = true)
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $old_state = $app->getUserState($key);
        $cur_state = (!is_null($old_state)) ? $old_state : $default;
        $new_state = JRequest::getVar($request, $old_state, 'default', $type);

        if (($cur_state != $new_state) && ($resetPage))
        {
            JRequest::setVar('limitstart', 0);
        }

        // Save the new value only if it is set in this request.
        if ($new_state !== null)
        {
            $app->setUserState($key, $new_state);
        }
        else
        {
            $new_state = $cur_state;
        }

        return $new_state;
    }    
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function getToolbar() 
    {
        $document    = JFactory::getDocument();
        $document->addStyleSheet('administrator/templates/system/css/system.css');
        $document->addStyleSheet('components/com_jomestate/assets/css/backadmin.css');

        $controller='admin_listings';
        jimport('joomla.html.toolbar');
        $bar = new JToolBar( 'toolbar' );

        if(Joomla_Version::if3()) {
            $bar->appendButton( 'standard', 'new', JText::_('COM_JOMESTATE_ADM_ADD'), $controller.'.add', false );
            $bar->appendButton( 'standard', 'publish', JText::_('COM_JOMESTATE_ADM_PUBLISH'), $controller.'.publish', false );
            $bar->appendButton( 'standard', 'unpublish', JText::_('COM_JOMESTATE_ADM_UNPUBLISH'), $controller.'.unpublish', false );
            $bar->appendButton( 'standard', 'delete', JText::_('COM_JOMESTATE_ADM_DELETE'), $controller.'.delete', false );
        } else {             
            $bar->appendButton( 'Frontend', 'new', JText::_('COM_JOMESTATE_ADM_ADD'), $controller.'.add', false );
            $bar->appendButton( 'Frontend', 'publish', JText::_('COM_JOMESTATE_ADM_PUBLISH'), $controller.'.publish', false );
            $bar->appendButton( 'Frontend', 'unpublish', JText::_('COM_JOMESTATE_ADM_UNPUBLISH'), $controller.'.unpublish', false );
            $bar->appendButton( 'Frontend', 'delete', JText::_('COM_JOMESTATE_ADM_DELETE'), $controller.'.delete', false );
        }
        return $bar->render();
    }
```